# PL/SQL Inserting 1 row for each result in a select

Tags: plsql, for-loop, insert, procedure

I am writing a PL/SQL Procedure that performs a select based on input variables and then inserts a row for each result in the select.  I am having trouble debugging what is wrong with my query due my newness to PL/SQL.  I know this must be easy, but I am stuck here for some reason.  Thanks for your help!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE setup_name_map(ranking_id IN NUMBER, class_string IN VARCHAR2) 
IS
BEGIN

    FOR rec IN (SELECT NAME_ID FROM PRODUCT_NAMES WHERE NAME = class_string)
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO NAME_RANKING (NAME_ID, RANKING_ID) VALUES (' || rec.NAME_ID || ', ' || ranking_id || ')';
    END LOOP;
END;
```

According to the Oracle Developer Compiler... 'NAME_ID' is an invalid identifier.  I've tried putting it in quotes but no dice.  It also complains that loop index variables 'REC' use is invalid.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is no need for dynamic SQL here:

```
BEGIN

    FOR rec IN (SELECT NAME_ID FROM PRODUCT_NAMES
                WHERE NAME = class_string)
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO NAME_RANKING (NAME_ID, RANKING_ID)
        VALUES (rec.NAME_ID, ranking_id);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Better still you can avoid a slow row-by-row cursor approach like this:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO NAME_RANKING (NAME_ID, RANKING_ID)
    SELECT NAME_ID, ranking_id FROM PRODUCT_NAMES
    WHERE NAME = class_string;
END;
```

If you really did need the dynamic SQL you should not be concatenating values into it, but using bind variables:

```
BEGIN

    FOR rec IN (SELECT NAME_ID FROM PRODUCT_NAMES
                WHERE NAME = class_string)
    LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO NAME_RANKING 
                           (NAME_ID, RANKING_ID) VALUES (:b1, :b2)
        USING rec.NAME_ID, ranking_id;
    END LOOP;
END;
```